# Random project chooser for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, laravel-9

today I have two similar Laravel projects, they are exactly the same except for the Laravel version, the first is running on 5.5, and the second is the updated version running on Laravel 9. The Laravel 9 one is not in production because we need a way to test it and check if everything is working after the update. My question is if there's a way to redirect to some clients only the newer version. The projects for the clients are exactly the same.

In conclusion I need a way to show to like 20% of the clients the newer version, and the older version for the other 80%, is possible to do this? Is there a better way to test the newer project for errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laravel 5.5 is _way_ out of date... You should do everything you can to get it running on 9.x. As for testing, you shouldn't be doing testing in production... Define a test suite (PHPUnit, Gherkin, etc.) and get that all passing, do QA testing against the 9.x version on a server separate from production, fix any bugs/issues, _then_ release to production (or similar). As for serving 1 version to a subset of Clients, you _might_ be able to use a load balancer for that, but it would highly depend on your production environment.

Comment: Yes, 5.5 is outdated, because of that I want to update it, but is a very big project, is hard to test it all. how can I implement the load balancer solution? My setup is an ec2 aws instance running on apache

Comment: AWS definitely does support load balancers, but I honestly have no idea how to configure that for one server (ip) to use the 5.5 branch, while another uses the 9.x one, or if there's even a way to configure it to route 20/80% to one vs the other; that's all Dev Ops stuff that is beyond my scope of knowledge, sorry 

Comment: thanks, you gave me a huge help

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Content Delivery Network e.g Cloudflare or something like AWS' CloudFront. You will be able to then configure the quota's in terms of where the relevant traffic will be redirected to.

Here is a [link to an article on Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/understand-basics/traffic-steering/)

and another one on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

You can also check with your host on how to configure a similar setup.

All the best